# Expose the required fields in listing view

Tags: forms

I have created a content type say "Form" which have one of a field named as "gender" set as a radio buttons.
This radio button I want to expose or make it visible with its functionality when I am displaying it in a View which can be called as "Form display" on a listing page.
I hope my question was clear,if not then please ask me in comments.

Comment: Is not clear what you need. You want to set up a View where nodes of type 'form' are displayed with the field 'gender' as a form so you can modifiy the value of that field for each node?

Comment: @tunic I want my radio buttons to be activated in my listing page where user can select the relevant options in a listing view.

Answer (score 0):

Use hook_form_alter() on the views_exposed_form. You can then change the type from select to radios or checkboxes.